# How to get only 2 questions from an array of 4 questions! Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, random, arc4random

How can i set my random function to only get me 2 results. I only want to get 2 questions per array not the 4 questions. `random()` or `arc4random()`? Not really sure which is better or what are the differences between this two methods! This is a different situation because Im using an struct for my array of Question.

```
struct Question {
var question: String!
var answers: [String]
var answer: Int!
var img: UIImage!
var info: String!

}
//Here is my viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
questions = [

        Question(
            question: "How old it was Steve Jobs in 2009?",
            answers: ["10","30","19","20    "],
            answer: 3,
            img: UIImage.self(named: "steve"),
            info: "Steve"
                ),]//....Here is more code with other questions
}

var questions = [Question]()//my array with the questions
var questionNumber = Int()

private func pickingRandomQuestion() {
    let numberQuestion = questions.count

if numberQuestion > 0{
    questionNumber = random() % questions.count//I only want to get  2 questions not the entire array of questions.
else {
NSLog("Done!")
}
```

Comment: Make an array `[0..length-1]`. Shuffle that. Pick the first two entries. Use those as indexes into your questions.

Comment: my array contains `Strings` and `Int` thats one of the problems that I have with `arc4random()`.

Comment: Your array contains `Question` structs, no?

Comment: yes but I want to get only 2 questions not the 4 that i have!!!

Comment: Yes, so you want to refer to the linked question and pick two random questions from your array.  `let twoQuestions = [questions[randomIndex], questions[anotherRandomIndex]]`.

Comment: This is so hard to understand, I already try to implement your code but I don't know how use the correct syntax in my code !!! little bit more help my man

Comment: With two from four questions there are only six possible pairs: 12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 34.  If order is important then there are twelve pairs: 12, 21, 13, 31, 14, 41, 23, 32, 24, 42, 34, 43.  Pick a random number in [1..6] or in [1..12] and take the two questions the number indicates.